# Loading SSL module failed. One or more mapped methods are not available

Tags: delphi, ssl, encryption, client, datasnap

I have DataSnap client application (delphi XE6).
On PC where installed Delphi XE6, my application worked properly.

But on other PCs (Windows 7, no installed Delphi XE) I got this error:
"Loading SSL module failed. One or more mapped methods are not available"

Could anybody help me please.
Thanks in advance.

UPDATED

Project Options - Runtime Packages - Link with runtime packages is unchecked (win 32, release configuration) [pic](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qbcwo51t40xgo2r/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%82%202014-08-25%2022.58.19.png?dl=0)

If I will clear encryption filters for TDSTCPServerTransport component on the datasnap server side, the client application is working properly on any windows machine.
DSTCPServerTransport1.Filters.Clear();

Comment: Clearly the ssl libraries are not as expected. How are you distributing dependencies to these other machines?

Comment: I guess, "other PCs" are missing SSL libraries. You didn't specified the target OS, so you can check [**win ssl dist**](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/openssl.htm) or [**ix ssl dist**](https://www.openssl.org/source/)

Comment: - "Other PCs" OS - Windows 7, Windows 2003 server

- Project Options - Runtime Packages - Link with runtime packages is unchecked 
(win 32, release configuration)

Comment: ssl dist http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/openssl.htm did not solve issue

Answer (score 0):

Check which modules are **really** loaded, using ProcessExplorer from SysInternals pack. Your app can load libraries which are in %PATH% and already used by Teamviewer or VPN client or something else. So you may need to install library from OpenSSL site, install it and make its directory first in %PATH% environment variable.